# Angular 4 doesn't send some requests

Tags: angular, html, typescript, ionic3

I recently upgraded to angular 4, Ionic 3.   I'm getting some issues attempting to call a get method on web api.  Whats weird is that I'm reusing this code in other places and it works fine.

My only guess as to what it could be is that its related to the new HTTPClient Module, or related to RxJS/map

Currently I have an HttpInterceptor which looks like so:

```
export class HttpInterceptor extends Http {
    constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, public authManager: AuthenticationProvider) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }

    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        console.log('request being made to:' + url);
        var requestOptions = this.getRequestOptionArgs(options);
        return super.get(url, requestOptions);
    }
    //... 
}
```

This is my HttpFactory

```
export function httpFactory(xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: 
RequestOptions, authManager: AuthenticationProvider): Http {
    return new HttpInterceptor(xhrBackend, requestOptions, authManager);
}
```

In my app.Module I have register the factor in the providers like so:

```
{ provide: Http, useFactory: httpFactory, deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, AuthenticationProvider]  }
```

I've Created a provider base which links with my services it has a method GetList

```
getList(pageSize?: number, pageNumber?: number): Observable<Page<T>> {
    const searchParams = this.GetSearchParams(pageSize, pageNumber);
    const requestArguments: RequestOptionsArgs = new RequestOptions({ search: searchParams });
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/${this.route}`, requestArguments).map(res => {

        const items = <T[]>res.json();
        const mappedItems = items.map(e => this.mapEntity(e));
        return mappedItems;
    });
}
```

I'm calling this on button click from a page

```
loadLocations() {
  this.baseProvider.getList(10, 1).map(t => {
    this.locations = t.items
  });
}
```

When I run load Locations,  I've walked the code and I see that my super for the HTTP is getting called, my console logs:

```
request being made to:http://localhost:50926/api/locations
```

Yet when I look in the chrome network tab, Nothing is sent.  Additionally this code is done generically and works fine in other places.

are there new changes that I have to adhere to with HTTP interceptors now that I've upgraded to angular 4?

Comment: The HTTP request will not be made unless you subscribe to your observable

Comment: gah, I was confusing map with subscribe, please post as an answer so I can credit you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will also need to subscribe, otherwise the HTTP request will not be made.

`.map` is just used to transform the response.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
 let API_ENDPOINT = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
 let some_params = "params_here";

 this.http.get(this.API_ENDPOINT + this.some_params).subscribe(res => {
   console.log(res);
 });
```

need to subscribe your request.